# DayNight Ignore Particular Activities

Tags: android, android-night-mode

Is it possible to force android to ignore certain activities from switching day to night modes along with other activities?

At the moment a possible workaround is this:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      // Set the local night mode to some value
      getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(
                AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_...);
      // Now recreate for it to take effect
      recreate();
    }
  }
}
```

However, this forces me to recreate the activity every time. Is it possible to just create it automatically in MODE_NIGHT without recreating it irrespective of what has been set for the rest of the app?

Comment: No, it's not automatic. you must to write recreate().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    // use this to keep mode after exit activity
    // AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Call `setDefaultNightMode` or `setLocalNightMode` before `super.onCreate`

Comment: I should use setLocalNightMode() right? Because I do want this to be only for a particular activity?

Comment: Yes, use `delegate().setLocalNightMode` to use in a particular `Activity`, and You should use `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode` if you want to keep the mode also on Activity exit.